# Joining two tables and then selecting only info based on criteria in a third table

Tags: sql

So I joined two tables but I only want to select info from that join based on criteria defined in another table. I only want info from the first join where the actors name is in the popactor table.

```
select  h.movie,
        h.released,
        a.rating,
        h.actor
  from  hollywood.stars h
    inner join starmovies a on h.movie =a.title
    inner join popactor p on p.actor = h.actor
  where h.movie = a.title and p.actor = h.actor;
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. Also read [mcve].

Comment: Could you not get rid of the join on the popactor table and add a check against the p.actor in the WHERE clause. (ie `and h.actor IN (SELECT actor FROM popactor);`)

Answer (score 0):

First your where clause is useless as the 2 conditions are already in the ON clause of your joins so you could get rid of it. Then you have two ways to achieve what you are looking for : 
As suggested in comments :

```
select 
  h.movie,
  h.released,
  a.rating,
  h.actor
from 
  hollywood.stars h
  inner join starmovies a on h.movie = a.title
where h.actor IN (select actor FROM popactor)
```

OR as you already did :

```
select  
  h.movie,
  h.released,
  a.rating,
  h.actor
from 
  hollywood.stars h
  inner join starmovies a on h.movie =a.title
  inner join popactor p on p.actor = h.actor
```

Of course, if h.actor nor p.actor is the actor name on which you want to filter, you need to replace these fields in both queries with the right ones.